# Detect non existing flags of flag-icon-css

Tags: javascript, html, css

Please have a look at the code snippet.

I have a Datatable containing countries including the country code.

In my code i put the html together to build flag-icon-COUNTRYCODE so that the flag is displayed. 
However we have some records that do not have a valid country code so no flag will be displayed since there's no such entry in the css of flag-icon.

Is there a way to detect (with javascript?) that no flag is displayed for the invalid country code XX ?

```html
<link href="https://cdn.bootcss.com/flag-icon-css/2.8.0/css/flag-icon.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<i class="flag-icon flag-icon-it"> </i>
<i class="flag-icon flag-icon-XX"> </i>
<i class="flag-icon flag-icon-co"> </i>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/rrxt88xh/

```js
var ele = document.getElementsByTagName('i');
for(var i=0; i< ele.length; i++){
   var img = ele[i];
   var style = img.currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(img, false);
   if (style.backgroundImage === 'none'){
      console.log("No Flag!!!");
   }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.bootcss.com/flag-icon-css/2.8.0/css/flag-icon.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<i class="flag-icon flag-icon-it"> </i>
<i class="flag-icon flag-icon-XX"> </i>
<i class="flag-icon flag-icon-co"> </i>
```

Check for **background-image**, if the **background-image is none** that means no flag is available.

Hope this will solve your problem.